# If a duplicate question on Meta has no answers it shows up as ( answers) instead of (0 answers)

Tags: bug, user-interface

I recently had a duplicate flag on one of my Meta questions. I saw this prompt:

[image]

Notice how it says `( answers)` instead of `(0 answers)`.

[My question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392797/why-are-links-on-answers-being-underlined) (10K+ only) and [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392796) (10K+ only).

Comment: Hans (and a few others around here) can see those deleted posts...

Comment: On meta you can select a duplicate with no answers. It is a ["feature"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189782/meta-duplicates-dont-require-an-answer-dont-suggest-there-is-one-when-thats)

Comment: In this stage we can be happy it is not `(NaN answers)`